# Flink sql client throws ERROR when executing sql statment

Tags: apache-flink

env:
intel chip macbook air 2017 with macOS Monterey 12.5
flink 1.15
mysql 5.7

I'm trying to set up a demo to sync one table to another table in mysql. However, i encountered some issue when executing sql statement in FLINK SQL CLIENT.

Let's say there's a table named product in mysql. Then I start flink and sql client, "CREATE TABLE" and execute "select * from products". Terminal returned ERROR message which says [ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.debezium.relational.history.AbstractSchemaHistory

I downloaded debezium-core jar of most recent version and put it under lib path. Then it raised another error
[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.debezium.relational.history.DatabaseHistory

I checked version 2.0.0 alpha and 2.0.0 beta, DatabaseHistory only appear in version alpha and AbstractSchemaHistory only appear in version beta.

If I put those two jar files into the lib path. I get [ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TOPIC_PREFIX

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5lhf.png)

Is there anyone who could give me some advice, thanks in advance.

Comment: Manually arranging individual JAR archives isn’t going to help. Isn’t there a prepackaged, turnkey, distribution of Flink with all dependencies in-box?

Comment: The question is lacking information. You're mentioning Flink and Debezium, but the version numbers that you're specifying are not Flink release numbers. Are you trying to setup a CDC system with Flink? Which connectors and formats do you use. What changes have you made to setup CDC with Flink SQL?